# filter JSON response by javascript object property value

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm currently pulling the below response outputs; I am trying to create 2 simple filters, so that only 'healthyMeals' that pass these 2 filters, will display, or output.

**Current working output (before 2 filter):**

```
{
  "healthyMeals" : [
    {
      "id": 310,
      "avRating": 2.2,
      "name": "Peanut butter soup",
      "expireDate": "12-02-2017",
      "difficulty": "easy",
      "reviews": 999
    },
```

**Attempt (trying to add 2 filters).**

```
this.getHealthy = function(res, req) {

  var checkReview;
  var checkRating;

  function checkRating() {
   if (averageRating > 4.1){
        res.res.json({
        "message" : "pass",
        });         
      } 
   else {
        res.res.json({
        "message" : "Could not find meal",
        });         
      } 
  };
  function checkReview() {
    if (reviews >= 5){
        res.res.json({
        "message" : "pass",
        });
      } 
    else {
        res.res.json({
        "message" : "Could not find meal",
        });         
      } 
  };   

  db.Meals.findAll({
    where: {
      id : givenId,
 //   averageRating : checkRating(),
 //   reviews : checkReview()
    }
  })
```

The above two properties with comments, breaks app and doesn't work when uncommented out.

How could I loop through all `healthyMeals` property values of '`averageRating`' and '`reviews`' and if they pass the 2 filter tests, then, and only then display? If not message 'Not found' displays.

Comment: what are you trying to do? you are calling `db.Meals.findAll();` and with one `givenId` and two filter functions, but those filter functions responds a json which doesn't really make sense? shouldnt they return values for your to use in your findAll query?

Comment: How could I loop through all `healthyMeals` property values of '`averageRating`' and '`reviews`' and if they pass the 2 filter tests, then, and only then display? If not message 'not found'.

Comment: You are using MongoDB right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared your variables as `checkReview` and `checkRating` (which are also same as your function names) but you are using `averageRating` and `reviews`. You should declare the below variables:

```
var averageRating,
    reviews;
```